# Can't Connect to some Hyper-V 2012 R2 servers after Windows 10 Updrade on Domain

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, windows-10

After upgrading my PC from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, i am unable to connect to some of our Hyper-V 2012 R2 Servers from Hyper-V Manager.

Both my PC and all our Hyper-V servers are joined to the same domain, all the hyper-v servers are running 2012 R2 and were accessible when i was running Win 8.1. The odd thing is that I can still access 2 of them fine out of 8 Hyper-V servers we have. I receive the following message

> An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "SVR-VMH0".
>   Check that the Virtual machine management service is running and that
>   you are authorized to connect to the server.
>
> Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on Computer
>   'SVR-VMH0' because the object was not found. The object might have
>   been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on
>   the computer is running.

Nothing shows up in the event logs, and according to HVRemote everything seems fine on the client and server sides. It's very odd that i can connect to two of the Hyper-V servers but none of the other 6, they should all be configured identically.

I can succesfully establish a remote powershell session to all of the Hyper-V servers fine, so this seems to be limited to Hyper-V Manager. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Could there be a service pack or update difference between the servers?

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference, this was one of the first things i checked and they all appear to be patched to the same version. One of the servers i can't connect to has no VM's on it so i tried running updates and rebooting which hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  There are some suggestions about how to fix it, but also reports that the fix breaks other things.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cc9115d-5fce-4a64-a90f-d3fdc008b861/windows-10-build-10240-managing-hyperv-on-2012-r2-datacenter-cannot-connect?forum=winserverhyperv